# Some images 404

Tags: images, htaccess, 404-error

I migrated our old blog to the same server in the main root. For some reason a couple of images won't load up any more even when they are in the /uploads/ folder. When going to them as a URL I'm getting 404's but I can download them straight from my FTP (and work).

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

I was thinking of my .htaccess file but I'm not sure it this is the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^dreamix-studio.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.dreamix-studio.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the image file permissions. And check the path in page source to be sure the images are in the correct location.

Comment: Hi Songdogtech, I already checked and changed permissions. The path seems to be correct, even when checking the FTP root.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to update your wp_posts table with the new URL of the images. Look for the "guid" field for all posts of post_type "attachment". It may have GUID that points to older host like http://old-host.com/blah/blah/image.jpg. 
IF IT IS, change it to new host like http://new-host.com/blah/blah/image.jpg.

Comment: The GUID is not the URL. It should not be changed.

Comment: For me it is. 
Yes, I agree, it should not be changed. But I faced same problem while moving few of my WP installations and fixed them by correcting their GUID.

Comment: [Eventually](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6492) the GUID will not even be a valid URL. Please do not recommend to use it as URL.

Comment: updated the answer. It will clear up what I was talking about. Thanks for pointing out that it was bit ambiguous.

Comment: The GUID is never used to generate permalinks. Changing it cannot affect the asker’s problem, the only effect might be that all feed item get a new GUID even if the didn’t change.